# Organized trips for young single travelers?

Tags: tours, solo-travel, guides

I have 3 weeks vacation during Sep-Oct.

I'm an Israeli with excellent English. I want to fly somewhere.

and was thinking to join organized trips for young single-travelers.

I saw this site:

http://thedragontrip.com/

http://www.vodkatrain.com/Journeys/default.aspx --> I pass this one. 
Too short for every city.

Does someone know to recommend this one or suggest any familiar other?

Update:

A more detailed request:

`Where do you want to go? You've mentioned Vodka train - so are you keen for just Russia? If you could narrow down the countries you're after, and the things you'd like to do, we'd be happy to offer some suggestions`

I'm 27. Like urban travels, but enjoy nature as well.

Less interested in museums (only few in a trip). Mainly monuments, interesting buildings (Love architecture). Absorbing local culture by walking through the city.

I love to see as much as sight-sees as possible.

I love to walk a lot. Thought to use couch-surfing.

Plan to travel alone, so I though joining a group could be nice (but this is not a must).

Not restricted to a specific area.

I get 3 weeks vacation from work during Sep-Oct 12.
I thought to use the relatively long vacation to get further away than nearby Europe (but Europe is still an option)

Does anyone know of organized tours for the age of 20-30? (I am 27).

Have been to central Europe, Thailand, USA.

Wanted to visit central America, but I think trans-Atlantic flight are to expensive for such a sort trip.

Comment: Hi Elad.  At present this is a HUGE scope.  What type of trip? Drinking and partying, or just sight-seeing? Where do you want to go? You've mentioned Vodka train - so are you keen for just Russia? If you could narrow down the countries you're after, and the things you'd like to do, we'd be happy to offer some suggestions.

Comment: Would you consider a group trip in non-Central Europe then? Scandinavia, or West Europe perhaps? Can see a lot and there are plenty of tours leaving all the time which may be suitable.

Comment: Yes. I would like to travel with people at my age. Though for Europe I think one can manage byhimslef (not orgenized) no?

Comment: My first priority was east as this is something that requeries more than few days. But if you think 3 weeks are too short (expenssive flight) for tasting the east - That would be a handy tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are loads of tour companies that accommodate single travellers. I find it best to read up about the tour company before hand, some companies have a reputation for being all about partying and not about sight seeing and some, the opposite.

With any review make sure it's recent and for the same region as your going to. For example, a Contiki America and a Contiki Europe experience could well be different. I normally just Google the company to find out if I think they're right for me, their websites generally tell you a lot about them.

As for finding a tour and comparing them I have used [tour radar](http://www.tourradar.com/) in the the past it allows you to specify duration and max min cost and pick from common starting points.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find any review about the dragonTrip besides the trip adviser, which is inrelaible to me. can you help me google it? (I'll try again myself)

Comment: i also found this site it seems to be a wiki dedicated to traveling around china http://www.chinatravelguide.com/ctgwiki/Main_Page possibly not all relevant but you never know. I can't find any information on the tour company other than there website and the stuff on tripadvisor. How much cheaper is it than comparable trips. I always operate on if it looks to good to be true... I possibly is.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Intrepid Travel](http://www.intrepidtravel.com). They do both urban and nature small group tours. While they don't focus 100% on under-30 travelers, that's their target group. I don't know of any company that does good singles-only group travel. There are a number of woman-only room sharing companies but that doesn't sound like what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I meant that singles can join with no double room fine. That what I meant. I see the link you sent me is not for young backpackers, right?